# expect a string or class but it is undefined in react Android

Tags: android, react-native

```
class MyAwesomeApp extends React.Component {

   _handlePress(event) {
      console.log('Pressed!');
   }

   render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.hello}>Hello, World</Text>
        <Button
             style={{borderWidth: 1,fontSize: 20, color: 'green'}}
             onPress={this._handlePress()}>
             Press Me!
           </Button>
         </View>
       );
     }
   }

       var styles = StyleSheet.create(
          { container: {
           flex: 20,
           justifyContent: 'center',
           backgroundColor:'red'
          },
          hello: {
            fontSize: 20,
            textAlign: 'center',
            margin: 10,
            color:'blue'
            },
         }); 
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => MyAwesomeApp);
```

not able to do this

Comment: Include your imports. My guess is, that you didn't define Button.

Comment: Activate your JS Dev Mode at the Dev settings and look where the error is thrown - From my sight maybe also the Text (Hello, World) should be setted in "" or save as seperated var text = "Hello, world" and put it into your image like {text}, because of the ,

Comment: I am running your code locally(on mac) its working fine for me. i am not getting any error.:-)

Comment: Yes,Once i restarted the system it is working now,Thanks for reply